# Como replicar a mesma imagem no cabeçalho? C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagem, layout

Estou tentando replicar a mesma imagem no cabeçalho de todas as páginas, mas ela aparece quebrada. O que pode ser? É um programa feito em c#, asp.net.
Já pesquisei mas não consegui arrumar. Pelo que entendi, é algum problema no arquivo _Layout.cshtml, que está na pasta Shared. Olha a situação:

A imagem está na pasta Images, que coloquei dentro na pasta View/Shared. Segue o código do arquivo _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="~/Scripts/Js.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Cooperativa de Médicos do DF", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse text-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sair", "Index", "Home")</li>
                     <img src="images/icone.png" id= "simbolo" alt="símbolo dos médicos"/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <hr />           
        <footer class="text-center">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Cooperativa de Médicos do DF</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inputmask")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O caminho da imagem está errada, do jeito que está vai sempre buscar do caminho relativo

```
<img src="images/icone.png">
```

O que precisa é que, apesar da rota, ela seja direcionada no caminho absoluto ou partindo da raiz da aplicação. O prefixo `~/` vai deixar o asp.net resolver esse caminho para você.

```
<img src="~/images/icone.png">
```

E mantenha o arquivo da imagem em `wwwroot\images`, porque esse é o local adequado para ela.

Comment: Olá, Leandro! Quando eu faço isso, a imagem da página inicial que estava aparecendo, também não abre.

Comment: Você deixou o arquivo no wwwroot/images?

Comment: @KakaTakeda Onde está o seu diretório `images`